# .on('click') function not working after updating to jQuery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

first of all I'm sorry if this was already answered here, but none of the solutions I saw worked for me.
I'm updating an old website and after updating jQuery to version 3.3.1 my function stopped working and I can't wrap my head arround the problem.

here is my script:

```
(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(e) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            var hash = this.hash;
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 1500, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        } 
    });
});
```

and the order I'm loading my script files:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

The page jumps to the anchor established instantly. Has there been some function deprecation I've overlooked? It worked fine with 2.2.4.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

EDIT: Removed initial claim that .on() function wasn't being recognized.

Comment: Have you checked your developer tools to see if you have any errors? Have you tried adding a very simple event like `$('body').on('click', function(e) { alert('Here!'); });` to see if the problem is really with `.on`?

Comment: *"the .on('click') function itself isn't being recognized"* - So the handler isn't invoked at all?  First thing you could do then is remove all of the unnecessary code within the handler.  Focus on just the handler itself.  Also provide a more complete example which demonstrates the problem.  Is there an error in the browser's developer console?  Does the statement to *add* the handler ever get invoked?  Does the `"a"` selector match any elements at that time?  We need more information beyond "it doesn't work".

Comment: The `on` listener works as expected with version `3.3.1` https://jsfiddle.net/r68v5wpy/

Comment: are your links contains hashes?

Comment: @Scoots ok I made a rookie mistake `(function() {
  $('document').on('click', function(){
   console.log("OUCH!");
  });
 });` I was checking on the document and not on the body. it does indeed recognize the .on() function.

Comment: @Aereth next step I advise then is a series of `console.log('Debug info here');` inside each `{}` block, while watching the console in your developer tools. Maybe even one immediatley before you apply the click event shown in your question.

Comment: @Scoots yes I have, done that, meanwhile I added a possible answer that solved the problem to me.

Comment: Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your wrapping function is never invoked

```
(function(){
   //code here
});
```

It should be

```
(function(){
   //code here
})();
```

Maybe you meant:

```
$(function(){
   //code here
});
```

which is a jQuery shorthand for invoking the function when the DOM is ready

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem, should I invoke all wrapping functions on a script file? all other functions work well without being invoked.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - all `(function() {})` does is to declare an expression that isn't assigned to anything and thus isn't reachable or useful in any way.

Comment: @Aereth: *"all other functions work well without being invoked"* - Only if by "work well" you mean "don't do anything".  A function needs to be invoked in order to execute.  Sounds like you're making some false assumptions somewhere in code you're not showing us.

Comment: @JonasH no, sorry I'm not thinking straight, I indeed forgot to invoke the function. you are correct and my precious comment was wrong. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If your JavaScript code get execute before DOM ready or there is no anchor tag when your JavaScript get execute.

Try the following code i hope this will work for you.

```
$('body').on('click','a',function(e){
//IMPLEMENT YOUR LOGIC HERE
});
```

**NOTE:- Make it sure that your JQuery library file include before your JavaScript code**

Comment: thank you for the input, I've posted what solved my problem right under your answer.